How to propagate the value of an init-only property to an enclosed class?
I have a Wheel class with two init-only properties Spokes and DiskBrake:
public class Wheel
{
    internal Wheel() { }

    public int Spokes { get; init; }
    public bool DiskBrake { get; init; }
}

It is critical for the functionality of this class that these properties are immutable after the instantiation of a Wheel object. So it is highly desirable for the properties to be init-only, and backed by a readonly fields.
Now I have a Bicycle class that contains two instances of the Wheel class:
public class Bicycle
{
    private readonly Wheel _frontWheel = new();
    private readonly Wheel _rearWheel = new();

    public int FrontWheelSpokes
    {
        get => _frontWheel.Spokes;
        init => _frontWheel.Spokes = value;
    }

    public int RearWheelSpokes
    {
        get => _rearWheel.Spokes;
        init => _rearWheel.Spokes = value;
    }

    public bool FrontWheelDiskBrake
    {
        get => _frontWheel.DiskBrake;
        init => _frontWheel.DiskBrake = value;
    }

    public bool RearWheelDiskBrake
    {
        get => _rearWheel.DiskBrake;
        init => _rearWheel.DiskBrake = value;
    }
}

The intended usage of this class is:
Bicycle bicycle = new()
{
    FrontWheelSpokes = 32,
    RearWheelSpokes = 24,
    FrontWheelDiskBrake = true,
    RearWheelDiskBrake = false
};

Unfortunately this code doesn't compile. I get four compile errors in the init => _xxxWheel.Yyy = value; lines:

Init-only property or indexer 'Wheel.Spokes' can only be assigned in an object initializer, or on 'this' or 'base' in an instance constructor or an 'init' accessor.

Online demo.
Is anything that I can do to fix the compile errors, without compromising the "init-only ness" of all properties in both the Wheel and Bicycle classes?
Constraints:

I don't want to expose the constructor of the Wheel class to the outside world. Only the Bicycle itself should instantiate its wheels.
Replacing the init-only properties with constructor parameters is highly undesirable.
The shape of the Bicycle public API is optimal as is. I don't want to change it.


if you want something to be init-only, why not put it into the constructor (which the compiler does for you in the backing for an init-property anyway)? So determine the number of spokes on constcution of your bike: var bike = new Bicycle(frontwheelSpokes, rearWheelSpokes, ...);

@MakePeaceGreatAgain that's how it started, with the values passed through the constructors. The problem was that many of the values are optional, making the number of constructors to explode. I started with 6, then at some point I had 15, which became a big burden both to test and to use. Then I discovered the init-only properties, and their number was reduced back to 6, which is great. If only I could solve this init-only propagation problem... But it seems to be unsolvable.

I came up with SomeBody's approach quickly, but the efficiency is too low, and once the properties increase, it is prone to errors (record could be helpful). Actually I feel that this constructor approach is more feasible. Now that we have named and optional parameters available, having 15 parameters is not a big burden.

@shingo I used your record idea in a solution that I've posted as an answer below. Thank you for offering your help in this issue!

It is possible to recreate the instance of your wheel property in every init-setter. You have to copy the properties that you do not set. This has the strong disadvantage that you have to call a lot of unnecessary Wheel constructors, but you can keep your class design. The code might be (for brevity, only with front wheel):
class Bicycle
    {
        private readonly Wheel _frontWheel = new();

        public int FrontWheelSpokes
        {
            get => _frontWheel.Spokes;
            init => _frontWheel = new Wheel
            {
                Spokes = value,
                DiskBrake = _frontWheel.DiskBrake
            };
        }

        public bool FrontWheelDiskBrake
        {
            get => _frontWheel.DiskBrake;
            init => _frontWheel = new Wheel
            {
                Spokes = _frontWheel.Spokes,
                DiskBrake = value
            };
        }
}

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LzMdP5

Thanks SomeBody for the answer. Your answer certainly satisfies the requirements in my questions, so I'll accept it. Your idea is quite similar to Shingo's idea (who unfortunately deleted his answer). I am not sure that I'll use it in my actual project though. I'll have to weigh the pros and cons compared to the unsafe but more efficient alternative that I am currently using.

A common approach for complicated construction scenarios is to write a factory method or a class to encapsulate the construction parameters.
A class to encapsulate the construction parameters for your example might look like this:
public class BicycleCreationData
{
    public BicycleCreationData(int frontSpokes, bool frontDiskBrake, int rearSpokes, bool rearDiskBrake)
    {
        FrontSpokes    = frontSpokes;
        FrontDiskBrake = frontDiskBrake;
        RearSpokes     = rearSpokes;
        RearDiskBrake  = rearDiskBrake;
    }

    public int  FrontSpokes    { get; }
    public bool FrontDiskBrake { get; }
    public int  RearSpokes     { get; }
    public bool RearDiskBrake  { get; }

    public int    OptionalParameter1 { get; set; } = 42;
    public string OptionalParameter2 { get; set; } = "42";
    public double OptionalParameter3 { get; set; } = 4.2;
}

The non-optional data is set in the constructor (rather than using init) and the optional data just uses get/set properties.
With that, you can write the Bicycle class like this:
public class Bicycle
{
    private readonly Wheel _frontWheel;
    private readonly Wheel _rearWheel;

    public Bicycle(BicycleCreationData data)
    {
        _frontWheel = new Wheel { DiskBrake = data.FrontDiskBrake, Spokes = data.FrontSpokes };
        _rearWheel  = new Wheel { DiskBrake = data.RearDiskBrake,  Spokes = data.RearSpokes  };
    }

    public int FrontWheelSpokes => _frontWheel.Spokes;
    public int RearWheelSpokes  => _rearWheel .Spokes;

    public bool FrontWheelDiskBrake => _frontWheel.DiskBrake;
    public bool RearWheelDiskBrake  => _rearWheel .DiskBrake;
}

And you would create the Bicycle in two stages like this:
var bikeData = new BicycleCreationData(
    frontSpokes:    32,
    rearSpokes:     24,
    frontDiskBrake: true,
    rearDiskBrake:  false)
{
    OptionalParameter1 = 100,
    OptionalParameter2 = "100"
};

var bike = new Bicycle(bikeData);

I'm not sure if this is the sort of thing you're looking for, but it does solve the combinational explosion of constructors.

It's not uncommon to nest the creation data class inside the class that is to be created, and then to add a Create() method to the creation data class. That allows the creation data class to have access to private methods in the class that is being created.
For example, you could make the constructor private and force all creation to be done via the creation class like so (and also add extra validation on the creation data if desired):
public class Bicycle
{
    private readonly Wheel _frontWheel;
    private readonly Wheel _rearWheel;

    public sealed class Creator
    {
        public Creator(int frontSpokes, bool frontDiskBrake, int rearSpokes, bool rearDiskBrake)
        {
            FrontSpokes    = frontSpokes;
            FrontDiskBrake = frontDiskBrake;
            RearSpokes     = rearSpokes;
            RearDiskBrake  = rearDiskBrake;
        }

        public int  FrontSpokes    { get; }
        public bool FrontDiskBrake { get; }
        public int  RearSpokes     { get; }
        public bool RearDiskBrake  { get; }

        public int    OptionalParameter1 { get; set; } = 42;
        public string OptionalParameter2 { get; set; } = "42";
        public double OptionalParameter3 { get; set; } = 4.2;

        public Bicycle Create()
        {
            // Add additional data validation here.
            return new Bicycle(this);
        }
    }

    private Bicycle(Creator data)
    {
        _frontWheel = new Wheel { DiskBrake = data.FrontDiskBrake, Spokes = data.FrontSpokes };
        _rearWheel  = new Wheel { DiskBrake = data.RearDiskBrake,  Spokes = data.RearSpokes  };
    }

    public int FrontWheelSpokes => _frontWheel.Spokes;
    public int RearWheelSpokes  => _rearWheel .Spokes;

    public bool FrontWheelDiskBrake => _frontWheel.DiskBrake;
    public bool RearWheelDiskBrake  => _rearWheel .DiskBrake;
}

Then you would create it like this:
var bike = new Bicycle.Creator(
    frontSpokes:    32,
    rearSpokes:     24,
    frontDiskBrake: true,
    rearDiskBrake:  false)
{
    OptionalParameter1 = 100,
    OptionalParameter2 = "100"
}
.Create();


Thanks Matthew for the answer. You've shared quite a few good ideas. Unfortunately my scenario doesn't allow to change drastically the way the instances are constructed. I have to use a classic constructor. Regarding your first suggestion, it implies that some of the properties are optional and some aren't. In my case all properties are optional. A Bicycle can be constructed with all properties having default values. It's just that some properties are used more rarely than others, and these are the properties that I expose as init-only. The more common are set in the constructor.

In my case all properties are optional ... It's just that some properties are used more rarely than others, and these are the properties that I expose as init-only I don't understand what you mean here... An init property is NOT optional.

Are you sure that they are mandatory? I am pretty sure that they are not (demo).

Sorry, you're right - I was thinking of the required  keyword

This is a more sophisticated version of SomeBody's helpful answer, incorporating Shingo's idea of making the Wheel a record:
record class Wheel
{
    internal Wheel() { }

    public int Spokes { get; init; }
    public bool DiskBrake { get; init; }
}

Now I can implement the Bicycle like this:
class Bicycle
{
    private readonly Wheel _frontWheel = new();
    private readonly Wheel _rearWheel = new();

    public int FrontWheelSpokes
    {
        get => _frontWheel.Spokes;
        init => _frontWheel = _frontWheel with { Spokes = value };
    }

    public int RearWheelSpokes
    {
        get => _rearWheel.Spokes;
        init => _rearWheel = _rearWheel with { Spokes = value };
    }

    public bool FrontWheelDiskBrake
    {
        get => _frontWheel.DiskBrake;
        init => _frontWheel = _frontWheel with { DiskBrake = value };
    }

    public bool RearWheelDiskBrake
    {
        get => _rearWheel.DiskBrake;
        init => _rearWheel = _rearWheel with { DiskBrake = value };
    }
}

Some explanation is required, because a lot is going on with the above code. Each time an init-only property of the Bicycle is used, a shallow copy of the Wheel is created, based on the existing Wheel that is stored in the Bicycle's private field. Let's see for example how the C# compiler transforms the FrontWheelSpokes property:
public int FrontWheelSpokes
{
    get
    {
        return _frontWheel.Spokes;
    }
    init
    {
        Wheel wheel = _frontWheel.<Clone>$();
        wheel.Spokes = value;
        _frontWheel = wheel;
    }
}

The <Clone>$ is a compiler-generated method in the Wheel class:
[CompilerGenerated]
public virtual Wheel <Clone>$()
{
    return new Wheel(this);
}

A cloning constructor is also generated by the compiler for the Wheel class:
[CompilerGenerated]
protected Wheel(Wheel original)
{
    <Spokes>k__BackingField = original.<Spokes>k__BackingField;
    <DiskBrake>k__BackingField = original.<DiskBrake>k__BackingField;
}

You can study the entirety of the compiler-generated code in Sharplab.
So what happens when a Bicycle is instantiated as shown in the question?
Bicycle bicycle = new()
{
    FrontWheelSpokes = 32,
    RearWheelSpokes = 24,
    FrontWheelDiskBrake = true,
    RearWheelDiskBrake = false
};

This code causes the instantiation of 6 Wheel objects. Two are initially created during Bicycle's construction, when the private fields _frontWheel and _rearWheel are initialized. Additional 4 are created by invoking the init-only properties of the new Bicycle. Of all 6 Wheel instances, the last 2 are preserved and the first 4 are discarded and become eligible for garbage collection. The discarded objects are shallow copies, so their memory footprint is just the size of a default-initialized Wheel. The work required to construct them is minuscule, just assigning the backing fields from the original to the clone. Still it is work that could be avoided if the C# compiler was more helpful in propagating the init-only properties automatically.
I am still undecided if I'll use this technique in my actual scenario. I am using init-only properties for some settings of my Wheel class that are rarely used, so this miniscule cost will be rarely paid in practice. I am more worried about the repercussions of converting my Wheel to a record, because the Wheel is an abstract base class, and there are other classes that derive form it. So I may hit some other wall down the road.

It is all clever, but I cannot wrap my mind on a scenario where this is actually desirable, versus just having a private setter. I mean, it might make sense today, but will it do so to whoever see this code 1 year from now (even yourself)? Maybe it is just a reflex of my experience maintaining code.

@RodrigoRodrigues you mean internal setter, not private. The problem with the internal setter, which is the workaround I currently use, is that it allows the property to mutate. And if it mutates, very bad things are going to happen. In order for my Wheel class to work correctly, the Spokes/DiskBrake properties MUST be immutable. It's like the Length property of an array. If it was possible to mutate the Length by mistake, programs all over the world would be crashing with ArgumentOutOfRangeExceptions.

As an alternative, you could make the properties Lazy and store the init values in fields for use when the Lazy property is created.
This does require duplication of all the init properties in fields, so it's somewhat unwieldy, but I'm posting it just for the sake of interest:
 class Bicycle
{
    private readonly Lazy<Wheel> _frontWheel;
    private readonly Lazy<Wheel> _rearWheel;
    private readonly int         _initFrontWheelSpokes = 24;
    private readonly int         _initRearWheelSpokes  = 32;
    private readonly bool        _initFrontWheelDiskBrake;
    private readonly bool        _initRearWheelDiskBrake = true;

    public Bicycle()
    {
        _frontWheel = new Lazy<Wheel>(() => new Wheel { Spokes = _initFrontWheelSpokes, DiskBrake = _initFrontWheelDiskBrake });
        _rearWheel  = new Lazy<Wheel>(() => new Wheel { Spokes = _initRearWheelSpokes,  DiskBrake = _initRearWheelDiskBrake  });
    }

    public int FrontWheelSpokes
    {
        get  => _frontWheel.Value.Spokes;
        init => _initFrontWheelSpokes = value ;
    }

    public bool FrontWheelDiskBrake
    {
        get  => _frontWheel.Value.DiskBrake;
        init => _initFrontWheelDiskBrake = value;
    }

    public int RearWheelSpokes
    {
        get  => _rearWheel.Value.Spokes;
        init => _initRearWheelSpokes = value ;
    }

    public bool RearWheelDiskBrake
    {
        get  => _rearWheel.Value.DiskBrake;
        init => _initRearWheelDiskBrake = value;
    }
}


Yeap, this is interesting too Matthew, thanks for sharing. In my actual scenario though, I can't afford to access the FrontWheelSpokes/FrontWheelDiskBrake etc properties through a volatile field (the Lazy<T>.Value). My actual Bicycle class is performance-sensitive, and it's not intended to be thread-safe. And it's also memory-sensitive, so all these extraneous fields will eat my memory budget!

If it's performance and memory sensitive then the approach of recreating all the objects (as per the accepted answer) might not be that great either!

The performance hit in the accepted answer is paid only during the construction. It doesn't affect the subsequent operation of the class. I accepted that answer because it satisfies what is asked in the question, and I haven't mentioned anything about performance there. This answer also satisfies the requirements, but I can't accept two answers. And SomeBody came first! :-)

OK that's fair enough! But I should point out that the the Lazy approach only constructs the objects once - it's just that the construction is deferred until the property is first accessed. There is a performance hit, of course, because effectively there's an if (isCreated) for every access of Lazy<T>.Value. Performance-wise, it would be hard to tell which is the best approach without instrumentation. Also memory-wise, the cost of having the extra fields might not be as high as having multiple objects created - again, only instrumentation would answer the question.

If you don't mind exposing the Wheel class to the outside, you should have your properties FrontWheel and RearWheel declared of type Wheel, and let that class handle it's own initialization.
class Bicycle  {
    public Wheel FrontWheel { get; init; }
    public Wheel RearWheel { get; init; }
}

// (...)

public static void Main() {
  Bicycle bicycle = new() { 
    FrontWheel = new() { Spokes = 32, DiskBrake = true}, 
    RearWheel = new() { Spokes = 24, DiskBrake = false }
  };

}

If you do care that Wheel type is not visible on the call side, you would have to make Bicycle the owner of the interface to initialize and access the inner properties belonging to Wheel.
For that,  you would need to make those properties get-only, and add a constructor to Bicycle which the consumer of the class can initialize those Wheel values.
class Bicycle {
  private readonly Wheel _frontWheel;
  private readonly Wheel _rearWheel;

  public int FrontWheelSpokes => _frontWheel.Spokes;
  public int RearWheelSpokes => _rearWheel.Spokes;
  public bool FrontWheelDiskBrake => _frontWheel.DiskBrake;
  public bool RearWheelDiskBrake => _rearWheel.DiskBrake;
    
  public Bicycle(int frontWheelSpokes, bool frontWheelDiskBrake, int rearWheelSpokes, bool rearWheelDiskBrake) {
        _frontWheel = new() { Spokes = frontWheelSpokes, DiskBrake = frontWheelDiskBrake };
        _rearWheel = new() { Spokes = rearWheelSpokes, DiskBrake = rearWheelDiskBrake };
  }
}

// (...)

public static void Main() {
    Bicycle bicycle = new(32, true, 24, false);
}


Thanks Rodrigo for the answer. Unfortunately exposing the Wheel class to the outside world is not desirable. The Wheel functions as an internal component of the Bicycle class, so that I can isolate the code relevant to the wheels from the code relevant to the rest of the bicycle. I could put all the code inside the Bicycle and solve the init-only problem, but then the Bicycle would become two voluminous code-wise. Also I want the values to be initialized as properties instead of constructor arguments, to minimize the number of Bicycle constructors (I have already a lot of them).

Also if I put all the code in the Bicycle, I won't be able to reuse the Wheel-related code in my other wheel-equipped classes, like the Handcart.

My suggestion is to review your design / constraints. An init-only property is enforced to be assigned only during the construction. If Wheel is private, someone must call that constructor, and that is Bicycle. Now, if you want to pass the arguments as property assignment to Bicycle, then you got a problem: where to call new Wheel()? In the FrontWheelSpokes property assignment? Or in FrontWheelBrake property assignment? In Bycicle constructor? Remember: you can only construct the object once

The Wheels are currently instantiated inside the Bicycle constructor, and in order to make my code compile I have made the Wheel.Spokes property mutable (get; set;). Which I don't like at all. It looks like the C# compiler is not in my side in this one, forcing me to be extra careful to not shot myself in the foot by mistake.

Why don't you just make Wheel's properties { get; internal set; }? You would be able to set them outside of the constructor, but only you (no client outside of the assembly). And as Wheel is not public anyway...

In my actual project the Wheel is already internal. It's not the callers that I am afraid of. It's myself.

Well, there is no magic here. Your options are: 1) make your properties type Wheel with public constructor or init props; 2) keep Wheel internal and have corresponding public properties in Bicycle, which are set in Bicycle's constructor; 3) same as above, but have them set on specific methods like AddWheel(int spokes, bool disk) that you can call twice after Bicycle construction; 4) make those Wheel properties { get; internal set; }.

Rodrigo yeah, I have a lot of options, and they are all undesirable. It's not your fault. It's just that, apparently, the C# compiler is not currently able to support my scenario in an optimal way.
